# How do I set up Snakemake on SLURM properly?

Tags: slurm, snakemake, hpc

The admins blocked me temporarily because my jobs were running on the login node. I am not sure if I am setting up the `SLURM` profile and invoking `Snakemake` properly, as I am having a few problems other than this.
I am not sure how to monitor jobs submitted through `Snakemake` on the cluster.
Also I cannot configure the workflow to submit one job at a time.

The command I use is:

```bash
snakemake --use-conda --cores 40 -j1
```

And the profile config file reads:

```yaml
cluster:
  mkdir -p logs/{rule} &&
  sbatch
    --partition={resources.partition}
    --qos={resources.qos}
    --cpus-per-task={threads}
    --mem={resources.mem_mb}
    --job-name=smk-{rule}-{wildcards}
    --output=logs/{rule}/{rule}-{wildcards}-%j.out
    --error=logs/{rule}/{rule}-{wildcards}-.%j.err
    --account=account
    --ntasks=1
    --nodes=1
    --time={resources.runtime}
    --parsable
default-resources:
  - partition=el7taskp
  - qos=sbatch
  - mem_mb=100000
  - tmpdir=/users/user/tmp
  - runtime=2880
restart-times: 3
max-jobs-per-second: 10
max-status-checks-per-second: 1
# local-cores: 40
latency-wait: 60
jobs: 1
keep-going: True
rerun-incomplete: True
printshellcmds: True
scheduler: greedy
use-conda: True
```

Am I simply not using the `SLURM` profile and running `snakemake` on the login node regularly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually include the profile in your `snakemake` call, i.e.

```py
snakemake --profile slurm
```

See the [documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#profiles) for details.

If you don't then you are running `snakemake` on the login node.

Comment: Thanks, it was that obvious. I don't know if it should be in a different question, but I am not sure what the difference between `local-cores`, `--cores` and `threads` is.

Comment: There's a lot of information on this hidden in the documentation [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cluster.html#cluster), [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html), [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#execution) combined with [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/foreign_wms.html#integrating-foreign-workflow-management-systems) and [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#threads). I think it warrants a dedicated question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
snakemake --profile [your.profile]
```

Alternatively, you can put the profile configuration file you made into the directory,

```
$HOME/.config/snakemake/myprofile
```

then add the file path to your .bashrc file.

```
export SNAKEMAKE_PROFILE=myprofile
```

This will make the slurm profile global, and remove the need to call your profile in every snakemake instance.